Please help identify British criminal (comedy?) from about 1960s
I watched this film about 20 years ago, so maybe some things were different. I'm sorry for my memory.
The movie was almost sure British, however it might have been US, but with a British sense of humour. The movie was probably colour, and I think it was 1960s-1970s.
This was a typical British criminal story, taking action in present time (the time it was created), but maybe it could have been Victorian times (Sherlock-Holmes-like). The action took place in some mansion or big house. Few people were closed there and a murder occurred.
Then, there was a character who solved the case. However, what was most fun, the end of the film looked like this:
As in such criminal stories, all the people are gathered in the hall and listen to the solution of the riddle. The detective says "It did the person A, because it is proved by evidences 1, 2, 3". The film ends.
But a moment later, there is an alternative ending and the same scene, however the detective says "It did the person B, because it is proved by evidences 1, 2, 4". There was an alternate ending for each person, also the detective himself - and every solution was acceptable and believeable.
The solution of the case was left open, so in fact we did not learn who really did, but we could see that everyone could have.

Are you sure that at the end it was one detective presenting the solution and not a few of them? If the latter it can be Murder by Death. Here's the trailer.

@Hegemon No, I'm not sure - this might be the movie, thanks

Yes, the trailer looks similar. Could you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Peter Sellers and David Niven might have confused me that the film should be British

Related questions here and here.

The movie you're looking for is Clue starring Tim Curry.
As you say it's set in a mansion and is loosely based on the board game 'Cluedo'.
The lobby of the mansion has a black and white chequer pattern to it, further emphasising the link.
The end of the film does indeed stop and start with mulitple outcomes.

Thanks - I need to take a look too. At the moment I can't accept any answer.

The movie can be Murder by Death:

The plot is a broad parody or spoof of the traditional country-house
  whodunit, familiar to mystery fiction fans of classics such as Agatha
  Christie's And Then There Were None. 
A group of five renowned detectives, each accompanied by a relative or
  associate, is invited to "dinner and a murder" by the mysterious
  Lionel Twain. Having lured his guests to his mansion managed by a
  blind butler named Jamessir Bensonmum (...)

The only difference is that at the end it's not a single detective that provides several solutions, but each of the detectives providing their own version:

Each detective "solves" the mystery with claims that the butler is one
  or another of Twain's former associates, complete with backstories and 
  motives.

Here's the trailer.
